# How can I print undef values as zeros in Perl?

Tags: perl, undefined

I'm building a count matrix in Perl using AoA: `my @aoa = ()` then call `$aoa[$i][$j]++` whenever I need to increment a specific cell. Since some cells are not incremented at all, they are left `undef` (these are equivalent to 0 counts).

I would like to print some lines from the matrix, but I get errors for `undef` cells (which I would simply like to print as zeros). what should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Classically:

```
print defined $aoa[$i][$j] ? $aoa[$i][$j] : 0;
```

Modern Perl (5.10 or later):

```
print $aoa[$i][$j] // 0;
```

That is a lot more succinct and Perlish, it has to be said.

Alternatively, run through the matrix before printing, replacing `undef` with 0.

---

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @aoa = ();

$aoa[1][1] = 1;
$aoa[0][2] = 1;
$aoa[2][1] = 1;

for my $i (0..2)
{
    print join ",", map { $_ // 0 } @{$aoa[$i]}[0..2], "\n";
}
```

Comment: +1 thanks. I would like to get a row (`$aoa[$i]`) with zeros instead of `undef`s and then use `join ("'", @row)` to print with commas. How can I do that?

Comment: @David B use a `map` instead of the inner `for`.

Answer (score 10):

Use `defined` with a conditional operator (`?:`).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @matrix;

for my $i (0 .. 3) {
    for my $j (0 .. 3) {
        if (rand > .5) {
            $matrix[$i][$j]++;
        }
    }
}

for my $aref (@matrix) {
    print join(", ", map { defined() ? $_ : 0 } @{$aref}[0 .. 3]), "\n"
}
```

If you are using Perl 5.10 or later, you can use the defined-or operator (`//`).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.012;
use warnings;

my @matrix;

for my $i (0 .. 3) {
    for my $j (0 .. 3) {
        if (rand > .5) {
            $matrix[$i][$j]++;
        }
    }
}

for my $aref (@matrix) {
    print join(", ", map { $_ // 0 } @{$aref}[0 .. 3]), "\n"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an  example, please modify the code to your requirements.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @aoa;

$aoa[1][3]++;

foreach my $i (1 .. 3){
    foreach my $j (1 .. 3){
        defined $aoa[$i][$j] ? print $aoa[$i][$j] : print "0";
        print "\t";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: You aren't replacing `undef` with `0`.

Comment: As mentioned above my code that it is a sample, however I will fix the code to make it more acceptable.

Comment: That does work, but there is no reason to use the conditional operator if you are going to write it like that; just use an `if/else`.  The beauty of the conditional operator is that it lets you factor out the common code like this `print defined $aoa[$i][$j] ? $aoa[$i][$j] : 0;`.